# Laravel Getting value of another table using foreign key on Blade

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have two models Batch and Notices. The foreign key is correctly formed and data is saved in the database. Now I can't show the data on my listing blade.

Notice Migration:

```
Schema::create('notices', function (Blueprint $table) {
  $table->id();
  $table->string('noticeTitle');
  $table->string('noticeDesc');
  $table->string('file')->nullable();
  $table->unsignedBigInteger('batch_id');
  $table->foreign('batch_id')->references('id')->on('batches');
  $table->timestamps();
});
```

Batch Migration:

```
Schema::create('batches', function (Blueprint $table) {
  $table->id();
  $table->string('name');
  $table->timestamps();
});
```

Data dump from db is:

```
 "id" => 1
    "noticeTitle" => "Quae ea est temporib"
    "noticeDesc" => "<p>sa</p>"
    "file" => null
    "batch_id" => 2
    "created_at" => "2020-07-27 16:09:52"
    "updated_at" => "2020-07-27 16:09:52"
 ]
```

Notice model

```
public function batches()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Batch::class);
    }
```

Batch Model

```
public function notice()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Notice::class);
    }
```

Notice controller

```
public function index(){
 $notices = Notice::all();
 return view('admin.notice.list')
   ->with('notices', $notices);
}

public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'noticeTitle'        => 'required',
            'noticeDesc'       => 'required',
        ]);

        $notice = new Notice;
        $notice->noticeTitle = $request->input('noticeTitle');
        $notice->noticeDesc = $request->input('noticeDesc');

        $notice->batch_id = $request->input('targetedGroup');


        if($request->hasFile('file')) {
            $noticeTitle = $request->input('noticeTitle');

            $filename  = $request->file->getClientOriginalName();

            $request->file->storeAs('public/noticeFile/additionalFiles', $noticeTitle.'_'.$filename);
            $path = $noticeTitle.'_'.$filename;

            $notice->file = $path;
        }

        try{
            $notice->save();
            Session::flash('success', 'Notice Saved');
            return redirect()->route('notice.index');
        }
        catch (\Throwable $th){
            Session::flash('danger', 'Something went wrong');
            return redirect()->route('notice.index');
        }
    }
```

Now I want to get batch name from batch_id

Comment: Have you have defined the relations in the models file?

Comment: Edited- added model

Comment: Post your controller, query code

Comment: Edited- added controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you might want to change the function names of your relationships. Your notice has only one batch, so it should be `public function batch()` and a batch has several notices, so `public function notices()`.
You can acces your relationships like any attribute, so in your blade:

```
@foreach($notices as $notice)
   @php $batch = $notice->batch; @endphp
   {{$batch->name}}
@endforeach
```

Or even shorter (if you don't plan on using the related batch for anything else)

```
@foreach($notices as $notice)
   {{$notice->batch->name}}
@endforeach
```

This is all explained in the Laravel documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships

Comment: What's the purpose of `@php $batch = $notice->back; @endphp`? Why not using just `{{ $notice->batch->name }}`?

Comment: @MaKobi For a single attribute you could go your route, indeed (added to the answer). Most times (in my experience) you'd have more attrbutes on a related model, then I prefer to write it to its own variable once, at the start, instead of calling up the relation again each time.